# clone svn repository to other svn repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an existing CMS svn repository CMS_REPO. Now I want to use this CMS source code as a base source code for other project. So I created an empty svn repository ABC_REPO.

My question is how do I clone the CMS_REPO into ABC_REPO. I will develop on ABC_REPO. However, if there is any change to CMS_REPO, i need to merge the change to ABC_REPO as well. Instead of modifying source at two repositories, is there any easy way of doing it? I am using tortoiseSVN. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can is to create a synchronized READ-Only Copy of the first repository via svnsync tool. But you can't commit into the second repository, cause it's read-only. This can be done via Hook-Scripts (post-commit-hook) to update the second repository every time a commit is done.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 entirely different repositories, you have 2 entirely different repositories. So the code is copied and has no relation (in svn terms) to the original. Imagine your 2nd repo was hosted on googlecode, you get the idea.

That doesn't stop you from merging as normal using SVN, when svn merges, it applies the changes you made to one revision to the target. This doesn't matter which repo the source is read from, so you can happily use the revision range merge functionality to apply changes across repos. What you do lose is mergeinfo, so you cannot use the 2nd repo code as a branch from the 1st, that means you cannot perform reintegrate merges or similar that require mergeinfo. (or at least, I think I'm right there - you could try it and see if I'm wrong!)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I try to merge the source code from other svn repository. If the directory structure is changed, then I will always get the Tree Conflict error. How do I resolve that?  One more thing, Initially I need to clone the first repository to the second one, so that I can view the commit history of first one as well? Is there a way to do it?